# can you load up a text area with html but display the wysiwyg formatted output (im using tinymce)

Tags: html, tinymce

i have setup tinymce in a webpage for users to generate html data that i am putting on my website.

the issue is that i have existing html pages that i want to use as a starter.

I want to have the first time they go to tinymce page, it prepopulates the textarea with the wysiwyg view of the html file on my local disk.

is there any way to take an html stream and have it prepopulate a textarea so it shows the wysiwyg instead of the html.  i need to ensure that this conversion doesn't lose any formatting.

Comment: are you asking: is there a way to do this without uploading the file from your computer to the server? (I.E> to load content from a file:/// URL?)

Comment: how do i take an html stream and have it prepopulate a textarea so it shows the wysiwyg instead of the html

Comment: Sorry for not understanding... I'm trying! :-) Where is the HTML stream? I know the HTML is coming from a local file, are you sending the local file to the server, and that's where the stream is? Or are you looking for a way to load a local file using javascript?

Comment: sorry if i am not being clear.  The html files are on the webserver.  I can read them into a string of html.  I want to pass that down so this is put in the text area when the user first loads the page.  the issue is that i dont want to display html in the textarea but the actual wysiwyg formatting

Comment: i just changed the name of the question to be clearer (hopefully)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When set up to load onto an existing textarea, TinyMCE will display the HTML already loaded into that textarea. Load the HTML into the textarea on the server side. For example (pseudocode):

```
echo "<textarea class=\"text\">"
echo html_encode( html_stream )
echo "</textarea>"
```

And the JavsaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector : "text",
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ok after posting this I just saw your changes and I lack confidence that I am answering your question... sorry! Point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 1):

I have built a custom CMS with TinyMCE which does essentially what you describe. I have found when I prepopulate the textarea that TinyMCE displays as WYSIWYG by default.

The HTML can be read from file on disk, or stored elsewhere.

Have you actually tried yet?

Comment: btw, if you'd like to bind TinyMCE to a specific textarea (as opposed to initializing ALL textareas) the JavaScript call is:

  tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, target_id);

...where target_id is the id of the target textarea tag.